# How to situate background svg flush to bottom of parent element

Tags: css

https://realisation.github.io/sketch/

I'm trying to get that SVG to be the background and remain positioned flat at the bottom of the red section while the width and the height scales when the browser window is widened/narrowed.

I've tried a number of solutions with background-position, but none of them work -- it has to scale.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I can't do that because this concerns an SVG, which I can't add to the question itself, correct?

Comment: Sure you can...That's why we have Snippets.

Comment: Really where do I upload an image file in the snippets I could only see html/js/css.

Answer (score 0):

There IS an answer to this folks!

It's very STRANGE -- you do not specify the alignment properties of your image in your CSS, if it is an SVG, then you specify the alignment qualities in the SVG!

`preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax"`

Did the trick.